# x86 assembly call label at an address from string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm not sure if anything like this is possible with x86 assembly but can I

```
mov eax, string
call string

my_funct:
mov ebx, hi_msg
call puts32 ;say hi
ret

string db 'my_funct', 0
hi_msg db 'Hi', 0
```

I understand that I want to call the label at an address and I am giving it a string but can I convert the string to an address? if so how? seems to triple fault when I try any suggestions as to how I might do this if at all possible?

---

thanks superultranova, scott hunter and the other guy who posted but got deleted, esm I think for your replies and help. I came up with

```
pop ebx ;num from stub
mov al, 2
mul bx ; mul 2 to correct offset (our funct_ptr are word not byte)
mov ebx, eax
mov eax, [funct_ptr + ebx]
call eax

funct00:
nop
ret

funct01:
mov ebx, hi_msg
call puts32 ;say hi
ret

funct02:
;not implemented
ret

funct_ptr:
dw funct00, funct01, funct02, 0
```

Comment: You cant do what you're trying to do, it just doesn't work in x86 since the label doesn't exist in the compiled binary as something that can be called.  If you could explain why you want to do this, and for what purpose, maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: im designing a stub function that pushes stuff on the stack one item of which is a number between 0 and 255. Another function (the thing im trying to do above) uses this number and further modifies a string eg. 'funct00' to 'funct1A' and calls it from a set of pre written functions labeled funct00: to functFF:

Comment: You could lay out a table of function pointers (addresses) that are stored in such a way that you will find the right pointer as you parse out the hex digit from the string.  Essentially, have a table of FF pointers, and index into that based of the number you parse out of the string, and call that address.

Comment: You're welcome, I guess I'll write that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above, regarding the string func00 - funcFF being passed to your program.

You could lay out a table of function pointers (addresses) that are stored in such a way that you will find the right pointer as you parse out the hex digit from the string. Essentially, have a table of FF pointers, and index into that based of the number you parse out of the string, and call that address.

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms, no; the runtime has no notion of what labels were used in the source code, much less what addresses they got associated with.  Obviously this is possible with debugging information (that's how a debugger can match up labels with addresses), but that seems to be way out of the scope of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You *can* actually do runtime symbol-finding if the symbols you want to find are in a dynamically-linked library.  For example, POSIX `dlopen` / `dlsym`.  (http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym)